# drag-drop in gridview .net website

Tags: asp.net, gridview, web

I have a gridview. in run time i need to drag the value from one cell of gridview and drop it in another cell of same gridview in asp.net website.

help do the need full.

Answer (score 0):

The YUI library has nice support for drag and drop.  With demos on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Another library is the Telerik one. I managed to get something similar working once but was a little inelegant. JQuery of YUI would be wise and in the long run worth the effort I would have thought.

When doing anything more than simple data display I have found the GridView nasty and a real time drain.

If writing from scratch is not an option it might even be worth investigating the Telerik Grid (it costs). Their grid along with their drag and drop could work. I am sure they are other .NET Web Forms libraries out there with something similar. Using libraries is normally easier than recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I totally recommend the jQuery and jQuery UI Javascript libraries for this task. See http://www.jquery.com and http://www.jqueryui.com

It should help you do the needful.